# Pascal Scripting: Canceling setup before {app} variable is set

Tags: inno-setup

I have some declarations at the [Dirs]-section in my Inno Setup file. I use "Inno Setup Compiler" and a normal text editor (Notepad++) for developing.
When I cancel the setup before choosing the install directory, the {app} variable is empty for sure.
I get this error (which is totally logic):

How can I fix that no error occurs after pressing the "Cancel" button and committing that I want to cancel the setup?

> Internal error: An attempt was made to expand the "app" constant
>   before it was initialized.

Can I globally set the {app} variable or give it a default value?

Here is a code snippet where I use the variable {app}:

```
[Dirs]
Name: {app}; Permissions: everyone-readexec
Name: {app}\bin; Permissions: everyone-readexec

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\run.exe; Flags: runhidden

[INI]
Filename: {app}\bin\myIni.ini; Section: Settings;

[InstallDelete]
Name: {app}\*; Type: filesandordirs; Tasks:
```

Thanks for help,
regards,
C.

Comment: It would be helpful if your question was edited to include the relevant section of the source code. It would also be helpful to know what specific software you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you should skip the code, which attempts to expand the `{app}` constant before it's initialized, or as a workaround you can use the [`WizardDirValue`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_wizarddirvalue.htm), which actually returns value to the `{app}` when it's being expanded. Even reference mentions that (emphasized by me):

> Returns the current contents of the edit control on the Select
>   Destination Location page of the wizard.
>
> **Unlike ExpandConstant('{app}'), this function will not fail if called after the wizard is shown but prior to the user selecting a
>   directory.** Rather, it will return the default directory name.

In the most recent source code you can see how the `{app}` constant is expanded on [`this line`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Main.pas#L995).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping, the problem got solved!

Before the user reaches the 'Select Destination Location' the {app} variable is not set.
My DeInitialize-Procedure looked like this:

```
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
  SettingsPath: String;
begin   
    SettingsPath := ExpandConstant('{app}')
    DelTree(SettingsPath + '\bin', True, True, True);
end;
```

What I did is I created a Boolean variable at the beginning:

```
[Code]
var appIsSet: Boolean;
```

I set it to false at initializing:

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
//    interesting code
appIsSet := False;
end;
```

... and set it to 'true' after the user has reached 'wpSelectDir' in nextButtonClick (see code snippet below:)

```
begin
if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
begin
    appIsSet := True;
```

The last step is to check in the Deinitialize-Procedure if the boolean variable is set. If so, he can access on it, if not - do nothing:

```
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var
    SettingsPath: String;
begin
if appIsSet then begin
    SettingsPath := ExpandConstant('{app}')
    DelTree(SettingsPath + '\bin', True, True, True);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Just to add to this. It seems you're creating some settings whose you delete when the setup is uninitialized. Wouldn't be better for you to use setup's temporary folder ?

Comment: You're welcome! It's better to use `{tmp}` since setup itself will clean it for you when it's done.